energy fluctuations in NVE ensemble in molecular dynamics
One can check if the timestep used in molecular dynamics is small enough by looking at the energy conservation in a NVE simulation. From what I understand, due to errors in the integrator (for the verlet algorithm $ O(\tau^4) $ ) and the modified hamiltonian, there are energy fluctuations. What are acceptable energy fluctuations? My best guess is that it should be smaller than $k_b T$.
In this post there is an answer I do not agree with:

fluctuations of about 1 part in 5000 of the total system energy per twenty time steps are acceptable

This is not an acceptable answer to me, as we can simply shift the total energy by a constant and the magnitude of the fluctuations  (1 in 5000) can change to anything. Where do the 20 time steps come from?

The ~3 orders of magnitude difference between the magnitude of the fluctuations and the total energy is a heuristic, same with the 20 time-steps. 20 time-steps is on the order of 20-100 ps, for most algorithms (assuming a time-step on the order of 2ish ps). Bond/angle vibrations occur on that time-scale, so if you have fluctuations more frequently than I would assume something is rather wrong in the algorithm/model. Ideally you would have more spaced out fluctuations in NVE (thereby preserving the ensemble's energy better). You must define your accepted level of tolerance based on your system. The magnitude also depends on your system (a few gas particles should have a smaller absolute energy tolerance (fluctuation) than a couple of thousand particles), but as noted in the answer you link to it is useful to define a fluctuation magnitude relative to the size of the energy itself (hence the ~3 orders of magnitude difference).
Whatever it is that you're simulating, play around with the time-steps to determine how it is affecting your fluctuations. Think about what physical conclusions you're trying to draw from your data and how fluctuations would bias them. Be concerned re. systematic drifts in the energy or fluctuations.
